AWS DMS adding null to non nullable column
Hi I want to move my data across from views that I setup into target tables. The target tables have a non-nullable autogen sequence column so for a normal insert if I don't specific a value, it will generate one.
However, when I tried a full load with AWS DMS, it seemed to have added a null value to the missing autogen column before inserting into target tables, caused a failure due to the non-null constrain.
What are the possible solutions to this? I am thinking as I excluded the autogen column from my views, is there an option on AWS DMS to move data according to the source DDL (my views) rather than to use the target DDL? i.e. to move a sub-set of columns only and do not append null to missing columns.
PS. target DB is PostgreSQL if it helps and DMS is using CSV to do the full load

Could you simply omit that column from the source schema definition and let the value generate at the target when the row is inserted?

@RossBush The source views do not have that column. It's AWS DMS that adds it back with a null value during the full load

When you say 'DMS is using CSV to do the full load', may I know what is the source type ?

@user1589188 - Are you using * for your column schema. You could make a mapping rule to ignore that specific column so it does not get pulled over, but will still be auto generated at the target.

@MANISH source is MSSQL

@RossBush I use mapping rule % to match all views under a schema, not mapping on columns. However, every view has different columns, can't really have rule for each view. Realistically have a rule to EXCLUDE the auto generate column would be great.

@user1589118 Maybe you could use schema tables and script out the table mapping exclusion rules using sql for all auto generated columns. Which source dms are you using?

Like Include *, Exclude(A,B,C)

You can try this to see if it works for you. This will create a mapping file with a *.* for tables and append transformations to remove all IDENTITY columns.
Another alternative, that may work, would be to convert all IDENTITY columns at the target to INT and see if the values come across. This should allow the source IDENTITY values to pass through as an INT value at the taregt.
SET NOCOUNT ON;  

;WITH IdentityColumns AS
(
    SELECT 
        SchemaName = s.name, TableName = t.name, ColumnName = c.name,
        CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t.name, c.name) + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) AS ColumnOrder,
        CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.name DESC ,c.name DESC) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS IsLastColumn
    FROM
        sys.schemas AS s
        INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.identity_columns AS ic on c.object_id = ic.object_id AND c.column_id = ic.column_id
)
,Prefix AS
(
    SELECT
    '{
        "rules": [' AS JsonValue,   
    0 AS JsonOrder
)
,IncludeAllTables AS
(
    SELECT
    '  {
        "rule-type": "selection",
        "rule-id": "1",
        "rule-name": "All Tables",
        "object-locator": {
            "schema-name": "dbo",
            "table-name": "%"
        },
        "rule-action": "include",
        "filters": []
        },' AS JsonValue,
        1 AS JsonOrder
)
,IdentityExclusions AS
(
    SELECT      
    '  {
        "rule-type": "transformation",
        "rule-id": "'+IC.ColumnOrder+'",
        "rule-name": "Remove IDENTITY '+IC.ColumnOrder+'",
        "rule-action": "remove-column",
        "rule-target": "column",
        "object-locator":{
            "schema-name": "'+IC.SchemaName+'",
            "table-name": "'+IC.TableName+'",
            "column-name": "'+IC.ColumnName+'"
        }
      }'+CASE WHEN IC.IsLastColumn=1 THEN '' ELSE ',' END AS JsonValue,
      ColumnOrder AS JsonOrder
    FROM
        IdentityColumns IC
)
,Postfix AS
(
    SELECT
    '] }' AS JsonValue, 
    999999 AS JsonOrder
)


SELECT JsonValue FROM
(
    SELECT JsonOrder,JsonValue FROM Prefix
    UNION
    SELECT JsonOrder,JsonValue FROM IncludeAllTables
    UNION
    SELECT JsonOrder,JsonValue FROM IdentityExclusions  
    UNION 
    SELECT JsonOrder,JsonValue FROM Postfix
)AS X
ORDER BY JsonOrder
    


Thanks for this. I tried testing with a single column with that "rule-action": "remove-column" but it didn't work. DMS seemed to have removed the value of that column from the source (I added the column back in the source views to test this), but DMS still migrate that column with a null value.

If you make the target column and INT instead of an auto-generated column, does the source value pass through?

Another more elaborate solution to ignore those fields would be to inverse the mapping file creation and include all non-IDENTITY columns. So, there would be no include '%' and you would implicitly include each table, and each column needed with "include-column", omitting the columns not wanted. I had to do this a while back when passing data through S3 buckets for some project. The table mapping files become rather large, but it is doable.
